# How to add Data factory contributor for a resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an access package, a subscription and a resource group.

I was going via [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions#:%7E:text=Let%20a%20user%20create%2C%20edit,role%20at%20the%20subscription%20level.). However, didn't get clear idea.

How to add data factory contributor for that resource group? Should I just go to the subscription -> then resource group -> IAM and then add? How can I make sure, it is in correct access package? I think data factory contributor is a built-in role in Azure.

Comment: Just a quick tip: this post looks OK because it has a specific focus, even after the request for links/tutorials is removed. Please refrain from asking for links to learning materials, as that can cause a Stack Overflow question to be off-topic, especially if that is the sole reason for posting.

Answer (score 0):

**Data Factory Contributor** is a built-in role in Azure

You can assign Data factory contributor role at a resource group level to the user, group or service principal

Go to your Resource Group --> Click on Access Control (IAM) --> Click on Add Role Assignment --> Select Data factory contributor role --> Go to members tab --> Click on Select Members and add your user, group or service principal to whom the access is required --> Click on Review and Assign

In this way, you can assign Data Factory Contributor role at a resource group level to the users, groups or service principal